# My javascript function skips over jquery code, is it because I have to install jquery into visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the showMore() function is run, several child elements are added to the id infoContent. But when the closeMore() function is run, it just skipped the jquery lines so that if the showMore() function is run again, the child elements are still there.

Here's my javascript code:

```js
function showMore() {
  document.getElementById("moreInfo").style.display = "block";
}

function closeMore() {
  document.getElementById("moreInfo").style.display = "none";
  $("#infoContent").empty();
}

function chooseImages(paintingName) {
  appendHeadings("Girl");
  appendImg("charcoal.png");
  appendImg("stilllifeimg.png");
  appendVid("random.mp4");
}

function appendHeadings(headingText) {
  var headingName = document.createElement("H2");
  var headingTextNode = document.createTextNode(headingText);
  headingName.appendChild(headingTextNode);
  headingName.setAttribute("class", "InfoHeadings");
  document.getElementsByClassName("infoContent")[0].appendChild(headingName);
}

function appendImg(imgName) {
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.src = "images/" + imgName;
  image.alt = "image";
  image.setAttribute("class", "InfoImages");

  document.getElementsByClassName("infoContent")[0].appendChild(image);
}

function appendVid(vidName) {
  var video = document.createElement("video");
  video.src = "videos/" + vidName;
  video.alt = "video";
  video.setAttribute("class", "InfoVids");
  // video.controls = true;

  document.getElementsByClassName("infoContent")[0].appendChild(video);
}
```

Comment: Did you include required `jQuery` files to the project? Without those, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Do you really need to use jQuery? Most of your code looks like pure JavaScript. You can try to replace jQuery piece `$('#infoContent').empty()` with `document.getElementById("infoContent").innerHTML = '';`.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with your Visual Studio Code. Its just an editor. Edit your question please into more clear one

Comment: @SMAKSS is right!, 
Just use pure js... because you are using it all over your code.

Comment: @AT-2017 sorry how would I do that?

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky YAY IT WORKS THANKSS. Also I want to use jquery because I have several other jquery functions I want to use which will simplify the code a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any errors in console *(Saying `$` is undefined or something like this)* You may need to import jQuery to your project by NPM/Yarn

```
npm i jquery
// or yarn add jquery
```

or by their CDN like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But since you are using pure Javascript in your snippet and only used jQuery for that `.empty()` in your `closeMore()` function its equivalent in JS may be useful for you.

So here it is, you can do that in JS by several approaches but one of the best one could be this:

```js
document.getElementById("infoContent").innerHTML = '';
```